# Retrieve list item data from a SharePoint list using Javascript snippet added as WebPart

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, code-snippets

I am using the below code as a basis to allow an end user to type in a surname and/or ID number and it simply retrieves all the instances of that surname/ID from a list and places them in a text field or something. This is on a SharePoint 2013 page.

```
<input type="text" id="Surname" name="Surname" style="width:200px" value="Enter the surname" onfocus="this.value = '';">
<input type="text" id="IDNumber" name="IDNumber" style="width:200px" value="Enter ID number" onfocus="this.value = '';">
<input type="button" name="button" value="Find Services used by person" onclick="findDocuments()">
<script type="text/javascript">
function findDocuments()
{
    var IDNumber = document.getElementById("IDNumber").value;
    var Surname = document.getElementById("Surname").value;
    window.open("ADDRESS HERE" + Number + "-FilterField2%3DSurname-FilterValue2%3D" + Surname)        
}

</script>
```

Note: ADDRESS HERE is the address of the list or library and I don't want it to necessarily open up a window, but to insert the retrieved data and put it into a textbox on the page.

To repeat with a bit more clarity, the user will see one or two fields, one field to type in an ID number and one field to type in a surname (or both). When they click a button it will look at how many instances of that ID number or surname are in a list and bring back how many different services this person has used and places them in a field.

At the moment I can only use Media Content added webparts to do this as I don't have the experience or resources to install Visual Studio or anything like that. Has anyone got any suggestions on this?

Thank you.

Comment: have you tried looking at CSOM? you can add simple content editor webpart add your scripts in there to fetch the data.

Comment: Is there a library for this CSOM which I can reference and then use?

Comment: you can check below links, should get you started. http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2012/10/19/how-to-use-the-sharepoint-2013-client-object-model-sp-js-from-a-client-web-part.aspx ; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185007(v=office.14).aspx ; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185015(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: That last donetmafia link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the REST service to retrieve list items via ajax using your parameters like this:

```
$.ajax({
     url:"/_api/lists/getbytitle('YOUR_LIST_NAME')/items?$select=FIELD1,FIELD2&$filter=FIELD1 eq '" + IDNumber + "' and FIELD2 eq '" + Surname + "'",
     headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"},
     success:function(data) {
            $.each(data.d.results, function(i, item) {
                  output += data.d.results[i].FIELD1 + " - " + data.d.results[i].FIELD2;
            })
     }
});
```